# Why does decimal input validation shows error only after publishing Razor MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have issue with decimal input valdation on Razor Page but only after publishing application. I have changed Default Culture by adding following code in startup:

```
var supportedCultures=new []
            {
                new CultureInfo("pl-PL"),     
            };
RequestLocalizationOptions locOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("pl-PL"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures ,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
   
};

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions);
```

When I launch application via Visual Studio everything works fine - I see decimal separator as comma and insert works fine. After publishing application using IIS or Azure App Services  error shows up only after sending form.
[Error Msg Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KanMH.png)

Answer (score 0):

your IIS version is probably different. Do you trying something like this ?

Here Example;

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="pl" culture="pl-PL" />
  <system.web>
<configuration>
```

See: [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bz9tc508(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

But, I think use should en-US